# If I know the masses, positions, and velocities of two objects, how do I calculate their trajectories under gravity?

Tags: gravity, asteroid, earth, near-earth-asteroid

I was thinking about the effect of a near-miss with an asteroid upon the orbit of the earth around the Sun. My goal is to figure out a formula I could use for a visualization I'd like to build to get a better understanding of the effects of a near-miss.

I tried to integrate the gravitational equation with bodies A and B, $a_{A}=\frac{Gm_B}{r^2}$, over positions from $t_{start}$ to $t_{end}$ but with my gen-ed physics background I got stuck on including the effects of gravity on the velocities themselves. I made the assumption that the gravitational interaction between the bodies is limited to a short enough time that you can disregard the effect of the Sun on either, so you assume that the only force involved is the gravity between the two objects, but even with just two objects, modeling this seems beyond my existing physics skills.

Is there a formula for this, where I can plug in the masses, positions, and velocities of two bodies, and it finds their positions and velocities at a certain later time given their mutual gravitational interaction?

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article on the two body problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem  If you subtract any linear motion of the barycenter, it reduces to a Keplerian solution with two familar elliptical orbits.

Comment: This will be an interesting problem. If you have the asteroid in orbit about the sun, passing close to Earth, and with a presumable mass much less than that of Earth, there would be a significant perturbation to the asteroids orbit due to the gravitation exerted by the Earth/Moon barycenter. I don't have a great cite for you, but there was a paper on a similar orbit determination of comets that may be relevant [Cometary Orbit Determination](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/books/CometsII/7009.pdf). I'm sure there is something similar for asteroids.